# Get Boolean Value of Each CheckList Items from Content Item in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have an item in Sitecore that contains a content section which is a Checklist. This checklist contains the names of multiple Active Directory groups that I have entered into Sitecore.

When the item loads, I am trying to loop through all of the check boxes that are in the Checklist to see if it is selected.

With help on a previous post, I was able to obtain the names that are listed next to each checkbox by using the following code (You can also see the commented out code that I tried using in order to obtain the value of he checkbox.):

```
    Dim ADCheckList As Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields("ADGroupAccess")

    If ADCheckList IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To ADCheckList.Count - 1
            If IsInGroup(ADCheckList.GetItems(i).Fields("name").Value.ToString) Then
                Response.Write("User in group. Now let's see if the group is checked.")
            ''' Trying to see if checkbox is checked or not. 
            ''' Dim isChecked = DirectCast(ADCheckList.GetItems(i).Fields("name").Section, Boolean)
            End If
        Next
     End IF
```

How can I obtain boolean value of the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field-type only stores the IDs of the items you have selected (as a pipe delimited list) it doesn't store the whole list of possibilities.

If you look at the `Template` that the item is created from you will see the `datasource` of the field. This will be a path to an item ie `/sitecore/content/home/myfolderofthings` the children of this item will be the options you see in the `checklist`.

You can, for example, loop through the items in the datasource location, get their `item.ID` property and see if `ADCheckList.Items.Contains(item.ID)` (or something similar) to get a boolean value.

Comment: Not having much luck finding the value. I've hard coded the Item ID to try obtain the value.    `Dim MyItem1 As Sitecore.Data.Items.Item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("522B9849-8C91-47AD-A158-4C2985A66F23")`    `MyItem1.Items("ADGroupAccess")`

Answer (score 1):

Stephen's answer correctly pointed out that the `checklist` field only stores the pipe delimited list of selected IDs, you can see this by viewing the raw values in the content editor or [Sitecore Rocks](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b).

I've included some example code that has methods to get a list of all the items shown in a checklist as well as a method to retrieve only the selected items. I hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace Cms.Website.layouts
{
    public partial class CheckList_SO : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var contextItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
                const string checkListFieldName = "List";

                SelectedItems.DataSource = contextItem.SelectedItemsInChecklist(checkListFieldName);
                SelectedItems.DataBind();

                FullItemList.DataSource = contextItem.AllItemsInChecklist(checkListFieldName);
                FullItemList.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ItemExtensions
    {
        private static readonly Item[] EmptyItemArray = new Item[] { };

        public static IEnumerable<Item> AllItemsInChecklist(this Item item, string checkListFieldName)
        {
            var fieldItem = item.Template.GetField(checkListFieldName);
            if (fieldItem != null)
            {
                var listSource = fieldItem.Source;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listSource))
                {
                    var sourceRoot = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(listSource);
                    if (sourceRoot != null)
                    {
                        return sourceRoot.Children.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            return EmptyItemArray;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Item> SelectedItemsInChecklist(this Item item, string checkListFieldName)
        {
            MultilistField checklist = item.Fields[checkListFieldName];
            return checklist != null ? checklist.GetItems() : EmptyItemArray;
        }
    }
}
```